# How can I solve the following question?

Tags: radicals

How can I solve the following problem?

$4\cdot 2\sqrt{x}=x^2$

Comment: You can get the square root sign with `\sqrt{x}` ($\sqrt{x}$). If you want other roots, you can get them, too. For instance, the $n$-th root of $x$ is `\sqrt[n]{x}` ($\sqrt[n]{x}$).

Comment: Wait, you meant $4 \sqrt{x} = x^{2}$? The current edit might be incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried squaring both sides?

Comment: Actually there are *two* possible solutions.  Do you know what the other one is?  Hint: square both sides to get $64x = x^4$.  What's the next step?  How do you know you can do the next step?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $4\cdot2=8=2^3$, and $\dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{x}}=\dfrac{x^2}{x^{1/2}}=x^{2-\frac12}=\ldots$

Comment: Don't forget $x = 0$!

Comment: Oh.... "hint".... right.  Not a solution.  A hint to get to the solution....

Comment: @fleablood: I debated mentioning $x=0$, but I guess that now I don’t need to!

Comment: I have solved it now, X = 4. But not on your way. I read from the above comment that I should square both sides. 

But on your way I can't seem to figure out how to continue from :
2^3 = x^1,5
I was trying with Log(8) / Log (1,5) but that wasn't correct either.

Comment: @Hithere: The other method works just fine and is probably easier. What I was suggesting is that for $x\ne 0$ you get $2^3=x^{3/2}$, as you did; then you can easily take cube roots on both sides to get $2=x^{1/2}$, and squaring gives you $x=4$. Since we divided by $\sqrt{x}$, we also have to check the possibility that $x=0$, and of course it does turn out to give us another solution.

Comment: Ah I see, alright. Thanks a lot for your help/time!

Comment: @Hithere: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

$4*2\sqrt{x}=x^2$; for $\sqrt{x}$ to be meaningful $x \ge 0$.

$8x^{\frac 12} =(x^{\frac 12})^4$; if $x^{\frac 12}=0$ then $8*0=0^4$ and $x =0$

$8 = (x^{\frac 12})^3$; if $x^{\frac 12} \ne 0$.

$\sqrt[3]{8} = x^{\frac 12}$

$2 = x^{\frac 12}$

$2^2 = x$

$x=4$

So $x = 4$ or $x=0$.